# how to compare two ISO time stamp in node js

Tags: node.js

time stamp look like 2015-12-09T12:09:30.000Z and want to compare current time stamp in node js.
tried moment.js but not liking to me.

time_since( ['created'] )

and time_since function is :

```
function time_since ( date ) {

    var seconds = Math.floor(( new Date() - date ) / 1000 );

    var interval = Math.floor( seconds / 31536000 );

    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " year ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " years ago";
    }

    interval = Math.floor( seconds / 2592000 );
    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " month ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " months ago";
    }

    interval = Math.floor( seconds / 86400 );
    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " day ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " days ago";
    }

    interval = Math.floor( seconds / 3600 );
    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " hour ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " hours ago";
    }

    interval = Math.floor( seconds / 60 );
    if ( interval < 2 ) {

        return interval + " min ago";
    } else {

        return interval + " mins ago";
    }

    return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds ago";
}
```

Comment: You should always post your code so that people can dig into the problem. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Date.now().getTime()
```

and compare it with your variable (of date type) like that:

```
Date.now().getTime() > yourVariableDate.getTime()
```

Comment: getTime () function is not defined

Answer (score 0):

First, make a Date Object from the String

```
var d = new Date("2015-10-17T13:09:02.807Z");
```

Second, compare it:

```
var compareable = new Date( new Date - d);
```

After that, it's just a date Object with the time between the 2 Stamp.
So if you're going for a String, you can do something like this as well (ES6)

```
console.log(`Time difference: ${compareable.getHours()}:${compareable.getMinutes()}:${compareable.getSeconds()}:${compareable.getMilliseconds()}`);
```

Comment: just used 
if ( compareable.getHours() < 0 ) {

  if ( compareable.getMinutes() < 0 ) {

   if ( compareable.getSeconds() < 0 ) {

    if ( compareable.getMilliseconds() < 0 ) {

     return compareable.getMilliseconds()+" mili ago";
    }
    return compareable.getSeconds()+" sec ago"; 
   }
   return compareable.getMinutes()+" minute ago";
  }
  return compareable.getHours()+" hour ago";
 }
but returning empty 

could you make a function for me?

Comment: Woooooooow! NEVER nest so many if statements!
And ofcourse it returns nothing....
You're checking if the amount of hours, minutes, etc. is smaller than 0....
Last time I checked, my clock lists minutes 0 - 60 ;)

Comment: so how i can list a time ago functionality of this ISO time?? :o